# Python Plotly - how to return current position of rangeslider?

Tags: python, plotly-python

I like to select a specific range of interest (e.g. period of 1 year) along stock charts and return the currently marked start and end position as a list at the push of a button. Optionally the data could be writen to  a csv file.
The range-data is later used to prepare datsets for machine learning.

Is there any chance to do that with plotly?

Range sliders: https://plot.ly/python/range-slider/
Custom buttons: https://plot.ly/python/custom-buttons/#methods

Answer (score 0):

So basically you need an event listener, and it seems that it's currently not supported out of box, see:

https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/2719

But maybe such workarounds: [plotly rangeslider how to determine if range is selected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40352171/plotly-rangeslider-how-to-determine-if-range-is-selected)

will do the job. However, seems to be tricky to get this to work in Python...